# How to make Ext.button.Cycle to use radio buttons instead of check marks?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

ExtJS `Cycle` button menu contains checked menu items, where we can select only one item at any time (see the attached picture or [live example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.button.Cycle)). This is confusing to the users. I want to know if there is any way to configure this Cycle component to show radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.menu.CheckItem` can be configured to be shown as a radio button, so we want to use it then we have to specify our custom menu with all items as `Ext.menu.CheckItem` and provide `group` config in each item to make it radio buttons.

```
{
    xtype : 'cyclebutton',
    menu : {
        xtype : 'menu',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'menucheckitem',
            text : 'Check 1',
            group : 'check'     // this will make sure that checkboxes will be rendered as group
        },{
            xtype : 'menucheckitem',
            text : 'Check 2',
            group : 'check'     // this should be same for every check item to put it in single group
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This rendered radio buttons as I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up item xtype as radio

```
 items: [{
        xtype: 'radio',
        boxLabel  : 'a'            
    },{
        xtype: 'radio',
        boxLabel  : 'b'
    }]
```